# Overriding list methods breaks pagination

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this ListAPIView:

```
class ProgramsHistory(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProgramsHistoryItemSerializer
    paginate_by = 5
```

And I need to add extra item to list view and I overrided list method like this:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    response_list = serializer.data 
    response_list.append(some_value)
    return Response(response_list)
```

But overriding list method breaks pagination for some reason. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Answer (score 4):

change your list code to

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
    response_list = serializer.data 
    response_list.append(some_value)
    return Response(response_list)
```